# How do you calculate the reduced costs of a Kineticist's kinetic blasts with infusions?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

The wording is unclear. If (for example) I had a 10th-level Kineticist casting a Thunderstorm composite blast (Burn 2) and used Gather Power as a move action (-1 Burn), then it is clear that blast has a total Burn cost of 1. But if I did Thunderstorm (2 Burn) and added the Thundering infusion (1 Burn), then my Infusion Specialization kicks in (at 10th level I can reduce Infusion burn by -2), and then used Gather Power as a move action (-1 Burn), does that make it 0 Burn?

I know it says Gather Power cannot reduce the Burn cost of a blast below 0, and Infusion Specialization cannot reduce the Burn cost of infusions below 0, BUT the description and sidebar for Gather Power says: "You can reduce infusions, metakinesis, and even the 1 extra burn for using a blast you don’t possess with omnikinesis. *All of these add to the blast’s cost*" which would seem to indicate the total Burn cost of the blast and infusions is taken as a whole before reductions are applied. Or am I just reading that incorrectly?

Answer (score 2):

### You apply all burn then reduce from the total

All [infusions](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Infusion-Su-) increase the Burn cost of the [Kinetic Blast](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Kinetic-Blast-Sp-) ability:

> Each time the kineticist uses one of her kinetic blast wild talents, she can apply up to one associated form infusion and up to one associated substance infusion.
>
> The burn cost listed in each infusion’s Burn entry is added to the burn cost of the kinetic blast the infusion modifies.

Both [Gather Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Gather-Power-Su-) and [Supercharge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Supercharge-Su-) applies to the total Burn gained that round. Note that all Blasts are gained from wild talents.

> Gathering power in this way allows the kineticist to **reduce the total burn cost of a blast** wild talent she uses in the same round by 1 point.

And finally, [Infusion Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Infusion-Specialization-Ex-) also applies to reduce this total Burn cost, by reducing the cost of infusions applied to your Blast, but cannot reduce the Burn cost from a Blast without infusions.

> At 5th level, whenever a kineticist uses one or more infusions with a blast, she **reduces the combined burn cost of the infusions by 1**. This can’t reduce the total cost of the infusions used below 0.

Comment: This seems incorrect given the answer below. I think  that the Infusion Specialization wording makes it pretty clear that the reduction only applies to the burn added from infusions, not from the burn of the blast itself (which conveniently makes intuitive sense).

Comment: @JaredGoguen i tried to not repeat myself by saying exactly what the ability says, and i quoted ("*At 5th level, whenever a kineticist uses one or more infusions with a blast, she reduces the combined burn cost of the infusions by 1. This can’t reduce the total cost of the infusions used below 0.*"). To me, it sounds fairly **obvious** that it applies to the cost of infusions, but maybe there was some confusion and i wanted to explain it differently.

Comment: Right, but it seems like you should touch on the fairly **obvious** case of when the cost of the infusions is less than Infusion Specialization reduction. Using the OP's example, the total burn would be 1 since Infusion Specialization cannot reduce the cost of the *burn* below 0.

Answer (score 1):

### Infusion Specialization

You can reduce the cost increase of *infusions* with [Infusion Specialization](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Infusion-Specialization-Ex-), **before** the Infusion(s) are added to the Burn.

In your example, a Thundering Infused Thunderstorm Composite Blast would cause 1 Burn after Gathering Power as a Move Action.

See the text of Infusion Specialization:

> At 5th level, whenever a kineticist uses one or more infusions with a blast, she reduces the **combined burn cost of the *infusions*** by 1. This can’t reduce the **total cost of the *infusions*** used below 0.

Therefore:

> Thunderstorm Blast +2 Burn
>
> Thundering Infusion +1 Burn -2 Burn = 0 Burn from Infusions
>
> Gather Power (Move) -1 Burn
>
> Total: 1 Burn

### Gather Power

[Gather Power](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Gather-Power-Su-) is a separate class feature that applies to *any* burn. If you were to Gather Power as a Full Round, you could then move and use your Thundering Thunderstorm Blast as

> Thunderstorm +2 Burn
>
> Thundering Infusion 0 Burn (+1 -2)
>
> Gather Power (Full) -2 Burn
>
> Total: 0 Burn

### Supercharge

[Supercharge](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist#TOC-Supercharge-Su-) (level 11) increases the Move action to a 2 Burn (any) reduction and the Full Round to a 5 Burn (any) reduction. At level 11, your Thundering Thunderstorm Blast with a Move Gather Power will cause 0 Burn (I think you can visualize the math at this point).

TL;DR:

- Infusion Specialization only applies to Infusions, and you do not apply the 2nd or higher point of reduction if you do not use more or more costly Infusions
- Gather Power can reduce the cost by more after spending a Full Round and starting at level 11, and applies to all sources of Burn